# Implementation of Red black tree in C++ using global pointer

Tags: c++, algorithm, red-black-tree

I am having trouble updating my global pointer in the following code,

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct RB{
    RB()=default;
    RB(int clr):color(clr) { }
    int color;
    RB *p,*left,*right;
    int key;
};

RB *Tnil=new RB(0);
RB *T=Tnil;
void insert(RB *T,RB *z)
{
    RB *y=Tnil;
    RB *x=T;
    while(x!=Tnil)
    {
        y=x;
        if(z->key<y->key)
          x=x->left;
        else
         x=x->right;
    }
    z->p=y;
    if(y==Tnil)
      T=z;
    else if(z->key<y->key)
      y->left==z;
    else
      y->right=z;
    z->right=Tnil;
    z->left=Tnil;
    z->color=1;
}

void print(RB *T)
{
    if(T==Tnil)
      return;
    print(T->left);
    cout<<T->key;
    print(T->right);
}

int main()
{
  for(int i=1;i<10;++i)
  {
    RB *x=new RB;
    x->key=i;
    insert(T,x);

  }
   print(T);
}
```

The problem is, the comparison `y==Tnil` in my `insert` function evaluates to false when I expected it to be true. After ending the function, `T` again becomes equal `Tnil`, as a result, so nothing gets inserted. Any help?

Comment: Probably not the only problem here, but I guess `y->left==z` should be `y->left=z` instead.

Comment: @jogojapan: Since the global `T` is shadowed by a local, the global `T` is not updated, and thus every time we come in, `x` is in fact `Tnil`.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Oh right, very good point... deleting my comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your naming is messed up.

You have two variables named `T`, one at global scope and the other as parameter to `insert`. Therefore the assignment `T=z;` in `insert` does not actually work on the global variable `T` but on the parameter and hence has no side-effect outside the function.

As a general rule, try to avoid single-letter variable names like `T`, `z` and `x`. They make your code hard to read and can easily hide mistakes like this one. Also, avoid doing non-localized updates from within functions. Updating global variables from functions is just asking for trouble like this. A better approach would be to have `insert` return a pointer to the new top-level node instead.

Answer (score 2):

you want to update global T. 
Therefore you should pass a reference of global T to insert:

replace

> void insert(RB *T,RB *z)

with

> void insert(RB * & T,RB *z)

(otherwise just a copy of global pointer T gets updated)

Also as mentioned by [ComicSansMS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/577603/comicsansms) in your example

```
y->left==z
```

should be replaced by

```
y->left=z
```

Best,

Jack